# django function based api not recognized in url.py - NameError

Tags: django, function, rest, api, url

I am trying to implement function based view for rest api on Django. It produces this error, how can I solve this.

```
url(r'^api/get_employee', get_employee, name='get_employee'),
NameError: name 'get_employee' is not defined
```

Below are some of my code excerps relating to this problem

https://gitlab.com/firdausmah/railercom/blob/master/railercom/urls.py

```
from railercomapp import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^doc/', SwaggerSchemaView.as_view()),
    url(r'^api/get_employee', get_employee, name='get_employee'),
```

https://gitlab.com/firdausmah/railercom/blob/master/railercomapp/views.py

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def get_employee(request):
    return Response(Employee.objects.all().values(), status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Comment: Use `url(r'^api/get_employee', views.get_employee, name='get_employee'),`

Comment: thats correct thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I can see from your views function that the function is correct but the import is wrong in urls.py
Either your import statement should be

```
from railercomapp.views import get_employee
```

or while defining URLs you should give

```
url(r'^api/get_employee', views.get_employee, name='get_employee'),
```

P.S After writing the whole answer, I saw @slackmart already solved it in comments. So full credit to him.